# Where to load resource from routes like /page/:id/subpage etc

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-router

I currently have app component that looks like this:

```
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'items', component: ListComponent },
  { path: 'items/:id', component: DetailsComponent },
  { path: 'items/:id/page1', component: Page1Component },
  { path: 'items/:id/page2', component: Page2Component },
  { path: 'anotherpage', component AnotherPageComponent} },
];
```

the id parameter is ID of a resource, that I load using http service and it is valid for all subpages. That means, I don't need to load it each time user navigates from Page1 to Page2.

Now the question is, **where to load the resource?**

currently do it DetailsComponent:

```
export class DetailsComponent {

  isLoading = true;

  constructor(
    private backend: BackendService,
    protected state: StateService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.route.params.pipe(
      map(params => params['id']),
      filter(id => this.state.currentItem != id),
      distinct(),
      tap(() => {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.state.currentCase = null
      }),
      switchMap(id => backend.getItemById(id)),
      tap(() => this.isLoading = false)
    ).subscribe(response => {
      this.state.currentCase = response;
    });
  }
}
```

I guess it is not best idea to do it in each page (Page1, Page2) etc..

I want thinking that I could have another `router-outlet` in "ItemContainerCompoent" within the `router-outlet`, but then how would I highlight links in  when user navigates between pages in the inner `router-outlet`

Answer (score 2):

What you need are *child* routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'items', component: ListComponent },
  { path: 'items/:id', component: DetailsComponent 
    children: [
       { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },
       { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
       { path: 'anotherpage', component AnotherPageComponent} }
    ]
  }
];
```

This piece of the documentation would be useful to you: [Milestone 4: Crisis center feature](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-4-crisis-center-feature)

Comment: It is still unclear to me, where to load the resource based on id. In my question, DetailsComponent and Page1Component are exclusive. Either one or another is displayed.... I guess I have to create parent component in `items/:id` path that will contain the loading logic and `<router-outlet>` and then move DetailsComponent to children

Comment: Yes, you will need to create this parent component. You can use _resolve_ techniques to preload data, then access it in child component, by `this.route.parent.data`. Anyway, there are many ways to achieve your needs. Routes or child inputs...